# Roll back error when updating cloudformation stack in the error posted occurs when using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

strong textAn error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the UpdateStack operation: Stack:arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:469058358707:stack/testdevMokiserverudagramclone/b47b45f0-82e9-11ea-b576-0a7df06cf190 is in ROLLBACK_COMPLETE state and can not be update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to **delete the stack**, fix your template and create new stack from it. You can't recover nor update stack in `ROLLBACK_COMPLETE` state.

Edit. Found the support for this in AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-service.html):

> This status exists only after a failed stack creation. It signifies that all operations from the partially created stack have been appropriately cleaned up. When in this state, **only a delete operation can be performed**.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation to prove your statement?

Comment: @MilanG Unfortunately, I don't have any official link. Just my experience. But some explanation is [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-can-CloudFormation-stacks-in-a-ROLLBACK_COMPLETE-state-no-longer-be-updated-and-can-only-be-deleted?share=1). If there is some new functionality which would allow you to updated or fix a stack in `ROLLBACK_COMPLETE` state without deleting it I would like to know as well.